# Extremely slow pypi package retrieval with i.e. pip

Tags: python, package-management, ubuntu-12.10, pip

Finding python packages using tools such as pip or easy_install takes very long, up to ten minutes, on my local desktop running Ubuntu 12.10. The same procedures are lightning fast on my cloud servers.

Things ruled out:

- The download of the package itself is fast enough
- regular DNS lookups fast enough
- when put a super-simple pypi mirror in between, with the 'simple pypi' interface, it is much faster.
- the pip log does not show anything useful, just long listings of urls visited.
- --use-mirrors doesn't help *from mhausler's answer*

Could it have something to do with the parsing of the listings?

I would be thankful for any tips on how to properly diagnose this, or what the problem could be.

Comment: Its super fast for the last couple of days! not sure why ... but previously it was super slow and times out occasionally. Maybe they got into some money or something.

Answer (score 8):

The main pypi index may be down or having problems.

Try executing

```
pip install --use-mirrors
```

to automatically use backup mirrors.

See `pip install --help` for details.

Comment: This is a great tip for many users, but does not solve my problem.

Comment: What if you configured it globally? That and other suggestions [here](http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/). Pypi has been experiencing some hiccups again recently.

Comment: Yes, have tried several tiers of config; from pip.conf to commandline arguments. It works fine one some other machines, but all my config is the same (I keep it in version control) so it must be some package conflict or firewall issue or something.

Comment: pip still have this option? When I tried to run `pip install -r requirements/production.txt --use-mirrors --default-timeout=3600` I got an `no such option: --use-mirrors` error.

Comment: Very late response but no. Pip removed this option because pypi.org is no longer known for being slow, and it seems like there are very few mirrors today.

Answer (score 3):

yes, the main pypi server is slow.

pickup another mirror server on <strike>http://www.pypi-mirrors.org/</strike>  pypi-mirrors is spam now-a-days , then

```
pip install django -i http://g.pypi.python.org/simple/
```

replace the url with your fastest mirror.

also you can save the setting by using `pip.conf`, check `http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html` for detail

Answer (score 0):

This was asked when pypi.org frequently had network problems, which is no longer the case, meaning that it's unlikely that this is actually happening unless the Python foundation reports a pypi outage or you are generally experiencing network problems on your install.

There is now two more problems that you might have come here as a result of.

- [An issue in Pip 21.0, explained here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10557). If this affects you, you'll either need to upgrade pip or use `get-pip.py` to install the latest one.
- [This open issue on the GitHub that affects some people on WSL](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8485).

In my case, there seems to be a general problems that throttles downloading files from the CLI, a problem I didn't even know could happen, however it seems wget and curl are affected too.